# Preprint Best Practices in Computer Science

Tags: computer-science, preprint

I truly believe in the benefits of pre-print distribution, however I'm not sure how to exactly proceed. Here are some questions I have in mind:

1. When should I make them available? Before peer-review? After camera-ready?
2. Where should I publish them? ResearchGate keeps asking for my pre-prints, although most of the ones I read come from Arxiv. And there's always my personal website at the University.
3. How do I handle versioning, or how many versions should I keep? Would that disperse any potential citations?
4. What happens to the pre-print after the paper is published? Should the pre-print make a reference to the publication DOI?

I would specially like to know what's the "state of the practice" in Computer Science.

Comment: *Should the pre-print make a reference to the publication DOI?* some journals require that you update the pre-print and add the DOI. Read the guidelines of the publisher carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practices I've seen in sciences, including computer science, involve

1. making the pre-print available upon/slightly before submission of the manuscript to the journal/conference,
2. publish the pre-print on the repository where the manuscript fits in thematically, i.e. where you find most pre-prints you read/cite (like arXiv oder Zenodo), or use your institutional repository, and
3. update the pre-print with the post-print (the version after peer-review but without the journal/conference layout) if allowed by the journal/conference, so that you have one or two versions available.

You can check whether you're allowed to update you pre-print with the post-print in [Sherpa/RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo), on the journal/conference webside or in the copyright transfer agreement you have to sign upon acceptance. There is also statet what other conditions apply, e.g. whether a link to the published version is necessary or you have to use a specific licence and so on.

Comment: About point 1: you may want to avoid doing this if the review process is double-blind (in which case making the pre-print available when receiving the paper is accepted could be a reasonable alternative)